# Using alias in mysql is not working

Tags: mysql

I am confused by the usage of `alias`. For example, the query below works fine

```
select * from 
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by prodid order by quantity desc) as 'rankin',prodid,quantity from sales
) A
where rankin=1
```

But when I modify it as shown in the snippet below I get the error: "Invalid column name 'rownumber'".

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by quantity) as 'rownumber' from sales
where rownumber = 1
```

Please explain the difference.

Comment: Erm, in which version of `mysql` did `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` [become available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `SELECT` is executed after the `WHERE` and the `FROM` is executed before the `WHERE` so it cannot be used in the second query but it can be used in that first query.